# Chrome Extension: Error at property 'message': Invalid type: expected string, found array

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am trying to create a chrome extension that displays the message from a python backend.

The python backend generates the output which is extracted in views.py

The function looks like this :

```
def get_summary(request):
    topic = request.GET.get('topic', None)
    data = summary_main.query_sen(topic)
 
    return JsonResponse(data,safe=False)
```

Here the function query_sen is a function already created.

The output data looks like:

```
[{"Title": "Deep reinforcement learning for inventory control: A roadmap", "Author": "'Robert NBoute', 'Joren Gijsbrechts', 'Willem Van Jaarsveld', 'Nathalie Vanvuchelen'", "Sentences": "They consider a realistic case study of a lost sales inventory system at the manufacturer ASML, who produces photolithography machines that are used in the production of computer chips."},
{"Title": "Machine learning at the service of meta-heuristics for solving combinatorial optimization problems: A state-of-the-art", "Author": "'Maryam Karimi-Mamaghan', 'Mehrdad Mohammadi', 'Patrick Meyer', 'Amir Mohammad Karimi-Mamaghan', 'El-Ghazali Talbi'", "Sentences": "Scheduling the processing of N jobs on M identical parallel machines such that the total makespan is minimized ( Silva et al., 2019 )."}]
```

Now, I want to use the output of this get_summary function and display as the chrome Notification message.

this is how the popup.js looks like for the chrome extension

```
$(function(){
    $('#keywordsubmit').click(function(){

      var search_topic = $('#keyword').val();


      if (search_topic){
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
               {topic: search_topic},
               function(response) {
                  result = response.farewell;
                  alert("Your summary is  ready !");

                  var notifOptions = {
                        type: "basic",
                        iconUrl: "icon-48.png",
                        title: " Summary",
                        message: result
                  };
                  chrome.notifications.create('SumNotif', notifOptions);

               });
      }


      $('#keyword').val('');

    });
});
```

This gives me the error :

Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of notifications.create(optional string notificationId, notifications.NotificationOptions options, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'options': Error at property 'message': Invalid type: expected string, found array.

I tried to change the datatype of the message. From

```
var notifOptions = {
                        type: "basic",
                        iconUrl: "icon-48.png",
                        title: " Summary",
                        message: result
                  };
```

to

```
var notifOptions = {
                        type: "basic",
                        iconUrl: "icon-48.png",
                        title: " Summary",
                        message: result.toString()
                  };
```

Then I got the output that looks like

```
[object Object][object Object]
[object Object][object Object]
[object Object][object Object]
```

How do I display the original output as the chrome notification message ?

Comment: did you already console.log(result) before you assign it to the notifOptions.message

Comment: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the data, and then [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it on the receiving end.

Comment: Okay, I resolved the issue. It was with how the output of data was actually in a list so to say with square brackets. I removed the brackets and now it works.